# 'Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\Action\FullFactory does not exist'

Tags: magento2, product, category, error, indexing

I have a Magento 2.0 store that I am trying to update the categories and products on. When I run it through the gui I get the following error message:

> exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\Action\FullFactory does not exist' in vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:103
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\Catalog...') #1 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Magento\Catalog...')
>   #2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Magento\Catalog...')
>   #3 vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\Catalog...')
>   #4 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\Catalog...')
>   #5

Any ideas? I'm a bit stumped and would appreciate any help.

Comment: remove var/generation and try again

Answer (score 2):

Try to empty the folowing directory's:

```
/www/var/di
```

and

```
/www/var/generation
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you try: composer install.

> cd rootFolderMagento 
>   sudo composer install